# Java instance variable of a static method

Tags: java, static-methods

when does instance variable of a static method gets memory in java?
it is perfectly right to create instance variable in static method (either in parameter or declaring inside the function), but i want to know when does the instance variable of static method is allocated memory, if no object of the class is created?

Actually i meant to say the local variable inside static method

Comment: The static members of a class will be initialized (and therefore also the memory will be allocated) as soon as a classloader first loads the class!

Comment: Do you mean local variable of a static method? There's no such thing as an instance variable of a static method.

Comment: *"it is perfectly right to create instance variable in static method"* Is that so? Can you show us an example?

Comment: Would be nice if downvoters could explain in a comment what is the problem with this question, because I can't see any.

Comment: @Jaroslaw: maybe because it makes no sense? answering shouldn't require guessing what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @NathanHughes a comment "it's unclear what you are asking" is more likely to solve the problem than a down vote. And the question is actually quite interesting.

Comment: Instance variables are allocated memory when they are called/incooperated in an action and once the GC determines they are no longer being used, it frees them up

Comment: Thanks a lost guys....   Yup it was my mistake to call them instance variable, actually i wanted to refer to the local variable inside static method..  Thanks for your answers and comments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the term `instance variable` is not accurate, I am assuming that you are asking about `local variable` such as `a` and `b` in the example below:

```
void method(int a) {
    int b = 3;
}
```

In Java, only primitives and references are stored on stack, objects are stored in heap when they are constructed. Stack will be cleaned as soon as the scope ends, heap is cleaned by garbage collector.

Here is an example:

```
public class Main  {

    static A a = new A();

    static void method() {
        int b = 2;
        C c = new C();
    }

}
```

The first time your code refers to `Main`, class loader will load the class and initialize all its static fields - object `new A()` will go into heap. Nothing more happens here, method `method` could as well not exist.

When you call method `method`, it will add value `2` on the stack, then it will add reference `c` on the stack which will be pointing to the object `new C()` in the heap.

When method exists, `2` and `c` are removed from the stack (there is actually no removal, but the top of the stack is changed to two positions below so these two values will be overriden whenever something else comes onto stack), while `new C()` will remain in heap until garbage collector triggers. It's likely that it will be garbage collected immediately as GC may detect that there are no more references to this object.

Comment: I think technically the JLS never refers to method parameters as local variables, but there's no harm in thinking of them like that.

Comment: Here is the JLS about variable types: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3

Comment: This is interesting how JLS is different from all the tutorials (including Oracle ones) and what terms we developers use daily. But good points, both of you.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable  or use parameter inside a static method, its not at all instance variable. Its a local variable and it will be initialized once the method gets invoked

```
static void methodTest(int i) {

String s = "Hello";

}
```

Here `s`  is a local variable to that method.
and `i` is the function parameter which is also a local variable to the method

Comment: Local variable `s` will be initialized when the method is called, not when class is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such thing as an instance variable in a static method.

If you mean parameters and local variables, those are allocated on stack (any created objects being allocated on heap as usual).

Static fields of the class will be initialized when the class is loaded.

Instance variables of a class will be allocated (and possibly initialized) when an instance is constructed.

Comment: Do you mean `stack` instead of `heap` (local variables)? And probably `instance fields` in the last sentence, instead of `instance variables`.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak good point about stack vs heap, thanks! Fixed. I've seen "insatnce fields" and "instance variables" both used alike to describe the same, so I opted to stick to the OP's terminology. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable) also seems to favor the later. [The utlimate judge](http://www.googlefight.com/%22instance+field%22-vs-%22instance+variable%22.php), too.

Answer (score -3):

The variable defined by static method is still local variable in scope of the method, just as if non-static method created local variable. However, problem is that the variable never gets garbage collected, as long as the class loader (usually main class, which gets "unloaded" only at runtime termination, which is like scratching your left ear with your right hand) is not unloaded and garbage collected. And objects get GC'd only if they are not referenced anymore, and in case of static fields, they have tendency to be referenced even when nothing uses them because of the behavior I described. So in large applications, where memory and resources are issue, it is pretty bad idea to declare anything inside static methods since you pretty soon pollute the memory with LOCAL VARIABLES that cannot be collected.

Comment: You can't declare static fields inside a method.

Comment: @PaulBoddington No, but the method holding that local variable is still loaded even after the execution and thus its local variables remain in the stack. And last time I checked, Java GC collects only unloaded classes, not methods or fields.

Comment: *"it is pretty bad idea to declare anything inside static methods since you pretty soon pollute the memory with fields that cannot be collected"* Since when is a variable _declared_ in a method a _field_?

Comment: @TheLaw You are mixing two completely different things - `local variables` and `fields`. The question is about the former.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Ok, I will edit my answer for the pundits, but I see no reason why those two should not be used interchangeably in conversation.

Comment: @TheLaw Maybe because they are two completely different things which are allocated memory at different times and have different lifespans?

Comment: @TheLaw "it is pretty bad idea to declare anything inside static methods since you pretty soon pollute the memory with LOCAL VARIABLES that cannot be collected" - any source? It's complete bullshit.